# jQuery doesn't locate specified anchors in bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the dashboard bootstrap template and I want to use jQuery to swap contents on click of specified links. Here's my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Membership requests</a>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a id="switch" href="http://www.google.com">List news</a></li>
                <li><a href="">List announcements</a></li>
                <li><a href="">List members</a></li>
                <li><a href="">List accounts</a></li>
            </ul>


...
```

**jQuery:**

```
    <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#switch").click(function() {
            alert('OK');
            $('#content').load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

jQuery does not locate the anchor with 'switch' id. What is the problem for this? Thank you

Comment: Your problem is that `$('#content').load(this.href);` in your case is a cross domain request, because your href is `http://www.google.com`. And as google does not allow you to load the content it will fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate to: [jQuery load doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235945/jquery-load-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a#switch").on('click', function(e) {
        $('#content').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
```

Might work. The event may be fires on some other elements.

Comment: If a comma is to be added after 'click', it works perfectly! But why would this work differently?

Comment: @Bravo if this code works for you then your problem was somewhere else. The only difference with this and your code is that `alert` is not used. (`.click(callback)` and  `.on('click', callback)` are equivalent)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ch57rkro/ Here is a fiddle. The load is running and it did not getting anything from www.google.com. Check your console window.

Comment: @Bravo Is this working for you? If not so, What is the exact issue. A fiddle demo will help us more