# jQuery load + Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem with jQuery load function.
I checked also this article, but it didn't help me:
[Jquery load doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235945/jquery-load-doesnt-work)

This is the load function:

```
function loadMore(eventId) {
    swal("Loading More");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/event/detail/"+eventId+"/more",
        datatype : "html",
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
            swal("Check console log");
             $("#detail-item.comments-bar.tag-fixed").load(html);
            }
    });
}
```

and this is HTML:

```
<div class="detail-item comments-bar tag-fixed" th:fragment="commentsMore">
   <ul class="comments-list" >
      <li>
         <div class="content">
            <p th:unless="${!comments.content.isEmpty()}" >No comments. You can be the first one!</p>
            <p sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">You are not logged in! Please log in to start commenting :)</p>
         </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
<a class="border-btn btn more" th:if="${!comments.content.isEmpty()}" th:onclick="'loadMore(\'' + ${event.eventId} +'\')'">Load previous comments</a>
</div>
```

The controller function returns HTML correctly, as I am logging this to the console. But nothing really happens in the view, it does not refresh, it does not change.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see the detail-item is a class and not an id, so replace this line of code

```
$("#detail-item.comments-bar.tag-fixed").load(html);
```

with this one

```
$(".detail-item.comments-bar.tag-fixed").load(html);
```

Hope this helps